# Jump to page AND page position in one action

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it possible to jump to an other page and in the same action also to a page position (at the new website) by clicking only one link?

For example

index.html -> clicking "link1" -> news.html is shown and view position is anchor "article1".
index.html -> clicking "link2" -> news.html is shown and view position is anchor "article2".

Hope, someone can help me?

Comment: http://www.hyperlinkcode.com/bookmark.php

Comment: Not on the same page. In my example the anchor position will be on the new website.

Comment: @Snatch the link suggested(anchors) does indeed what you seems asking.

Comment: U r asking about redirection right?

Comment: @Snatch that is exactly the behaviour the article I linked to shows you. It is in-built in to HTML as standard.

Comment: Yea, sry, my fail, I realize that until I saw the examples below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is easy.

In index.html, add a `#identifier` after the href string like so

```
<a href = "news.html#article1">Article 1</a>
<a href = "news.html#article2">Article 2</a>
```

and in news.html, insert the `<a>` tag with `name` attribute just above the content that you want displayed in view

```
<a name="article1"></a>
<p>Some Article1 Content</p>

<a name="article2"></a>
<p>Some Article2 Content</p>
```

So, now, if someone clicks Article 1, it will show `news.html` with Article 1 in view.

Note that this only works if the page content is long enough to require y-axis scroll bars in the browser window.

Comment: Wow, thats really easy, thx! ;) - and thx for the scroll tip!

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the anchor to the link:

```
<a href="news.html#article1">Link 1</a>
<a href="news.html#article2">Link 2</a>
```

Comment: Thx for support! Thats really easy ;).